# 3D Matrix Multiplication in CUDA

Tags: matrix, cuda, implementation, matrix-multiplication

I am currently trying to implement a product of Matrices in CUDA : 
The first Matrix is a 3D matrix (N,M,Z) and the second one is a 2D Matrix (M, L ).
I cannot see what is wrong in my code for this multiplication.
Could someone help me on this issue?
Thank you

Here is my Kernel:

```
__global__ void matrixMul(float * A, float * B, float * C,int N, int M, int Z, int L) {
int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int idy = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

for(int z=0; z<width; z++){
    C[idx*width+idy] +=  A[idy + idx*width ]*B[idx*width+idy+z*width*height];
}

}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? And wouldn't it be better, to name the kernel `matrixMult` instead of `matrixAdd`?

Comment: You are trying to calculate a hypermatrix product? or something else?

Comment: Hello, My isssue is the fastest way to get my results. I am trying to run a concurrent computation of this product. I have some doubt regarding my indexing. I think that C(i,j,t) = sum i=1 to n ( a (r + it)*B(i,t)... The previous indexation has given some strange results..

Comment: You should read about usage of shared memory and working with thread blocks of special sizes (warps) to optimize your code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see is row/column numbering.

`z` should be in both `A` and `B` matrix indexes. The rule of multiplying matrices states:

(AB)ij = sum(k) Aik * Bkj

so I assume for your example would be someting like

(AB)ij = sum(k,e) Aik * Bkje

Comment: I have changed my indexes in the following way. I know both are correct since I am able to get back the original matrices but once the product is performed, the result is totally wrong.            for(int z=0; z<width; z++)
              C[idx*width+idy] = A[idy + idx*width]*B[idy*l + idx];